# Consuming WCF service (WsHttp Binding) in NodeJs

Tags: c#, node.js, web-services, wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF service using NodeJS. I tried `BasicHttpBinding` with `security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"`. It is working fine. 
But if I try to consume the service with `WsHttpBinding` and `security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"`, the following error is thrown:

> "The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData' is incorrect or because
>   the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
>   because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context
>   token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to
>   inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding."

[image: Error]

This is my web config

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <!--Maximum size of the message which can be processed by the binding is 100 MB-->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" name="WsHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

This is my NodeJS file

```
var WSHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').WSHttpBinding
  , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
  , binding = new WSHttpBinding(
    { 
      SecurityMode: "TransportWithMessageCredential"
    , TransportClientCredentialType:"None"
    , MessageClientCredentialType: "UserName"
    })
  , proxy = new Proxy(binding, "https://localhost:44301/Service1.svc")
  , message = '<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">'+
      '<Body>'+
        '<GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
            '<value>12345</value>'+
        '</GetData>'+
      '</Body>'+
   '</Envelope>'

   proxy.ClientCredentials.Username.Username = "xyz"
   proxy.ClientCredentials.Username.Password = "xyz"
   proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData",

  function(response, ctx) {
      console.log(response)
  });
```

Comment: Adding establishSecurityContext="false" did the job....
But i am not sure how it will affect the security!
Can someone explain?

Comment: how does your wcf request look like? set up a wcf client and than publish here what it sends vs what nodejs sends.